# Copy symbol properties from object

Tags: javascript, node.js, symbols

```
const c = {};
const s = Symbol()
c[s] = true;
```

how can I view c's properties including the symbol properties? if I do:

```
for(const [k,v] of Object.entries(c)){
  console.log(k,v);
}
```

that won't get my non-enumerable properties like symbols are by default? I tried this:

```
for(const k of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(c)){
  console.log(k,c[k]);
}
```

but that list is empty also.

Comment: There is [`Object.getOwnPropertySymbols()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertySymbols)

Comment: ah interesting, yeah `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(c)` was not working either as I just updated the OP

Comment: I wonder if there is a way to enumerate everything in one shot, otherwise I have to loop 2x.

Answer (score 4):

You access those in a slightly different manner using:

```
let c = {
  [Symbol("a")]: true
}

const keys = Reflect.ownKeys(c);
```

which is equivalent to

```
const keys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(c).concat(Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(c))
```

The `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()` method returns an array of all properties (enumerable or not) found directly upon a given object.

The `Object.getOwnPropertySymbols()` method returns an array of all symbol properties found directly upon a given object.